# Difficulties configuring openCV library in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

I'm trying to configure my Visual C++ to use the openCV libraries.  I've followed the instructions on OpenCV website http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VisualC%2B%2B...

```
// OpenCV_Helloworld.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
// Created for build/install tutorial, Microsoft Visual Studio and OpenCV 2.2.0

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        // Open the file.
        IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("photo.jpg");
        if (!img) {
                printf("Error: Couldn't open the image file.\n");
                return 1;
        }

        // Display the image.
        cvNamedWindow("Image:", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("Image:", img);

        // Wait for the user to press a key in the GUI window.
        cvWaitKey(0);

        // Free the resources.
        cvDestroyWindow("Image:");
        cvReleaseImage(&img);

        return 0;
}
```

I have altered the include and library directories in VC++ directories inside the Property Pages, and have added the additional dependencies.  However, when I try and load an image with the same header files as the sample code, it says that cvLoadImage is undefined, as is cvNamedWindow

```
IplImage *img = cvLoadImage("JellyFish.jpg");
```

Any suggestions as to where I might have my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might try making sure your Code Generation for your project is Multi-threaded DLL (or Multi-threaded Debug DLL).

Comment: Darn! Well, I'm pretty much just guessing at this point....Try changing the Character Set of your project to Not Set.

Comment: Nope, no luck there either.  Not set doesn't change anything.

Comment: Well, sorry, I'm out of ideas without seeing your exact VS2010 project file. If you find out the reason, make sure you post the answer here!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure using CMake. Get OpenCV 2.2 and try the following step by step guide.

http://kaushalsolanki.com/2011/01/compile-and-set-up-opencv-for-visual-studio-2010-with-64-bits-support-ipp-7-0-and-tbb/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error but i finally fixed it
I am using opencv 2.3
what I did was I changed all the additional dependencies 
from opencv_core220d.lib to opencv_core231d.lib
we need to change all of the dependencies in the same way

and then i copied all the *.dll files from my bin>>debug folder to 
where i had new project that is
helloworld>>helloworld

for example 
C:\opencv\build\bin\debug  copy all *.dll files to
C:\opencv\Projects\helloworld\helloworld